# selenium unable to locate input object in iframe

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

My goal is to automatically fill out the form at https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en using selenium.

I am able to fill in a password but I am still struggling to fill a username in.

The username field is inside an iframe. The HTML for said iframe is the following:

```
<iframe title="Registration form" scrolling="no" class="top" data-name="top" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-top-navigation" src="https://secure.protonmail.com/abusev2.iframe.html?name=top">
    #document
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>...</head>
        <body>
            <div id="app" data-name="top">
                <div class="formList">
                    <div class="field field-usernameInput">
                        <div class="group-username">
                            <label for="username">Choose username</label>
                            <input placeholder="Choose username" required="" name="username" messages="[object Object]" iframename="top" pattern=".{1,40}" id="username" class="input">
                            <div class="field field-select"><label for="domain">Select a domain</label><div class="select-mask"><select component="domains" name="domain" id="domain"><option value="protonmail.com">protonmail.com</option><option value="protonmail.ch">protonmail.ch</option></select><i>▼</i></div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
    </iframe>
```

In order to switch selenium to the iframe I used

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
```

That does not give me an exception.
However I am now unable to find the input object to do .send_keys().

I've tried

```
driver.find_element_by_id('username')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('input')
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('input')
driver.find_element_by_name('username')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="username"]')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#username')
```

but every time I get the same exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: *whatever I searched for*
```

When I tried

```
driver.find_element_by_id('app') #first div object in the iframe
```

I didn't get any exceptions.
If I don't switch to the iframe I cannot find this which leads me to believe that switching to the iframe worked.
I am however unable to find any of the other div objects with any of the mentioned methods.

To conclude: I have no idea why I am unable to find the input object with selenium to automatically put in a username afterwords and would greatly appreciate ideas on what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would get the first iframe use a more targeted xpath.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//iframe[@title='Registration form'])[1]"))
```

So to target the first iframe and wait for the username and send a key to it.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en')
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"(//iframe[@title='Registration form'])[1]")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//div[@class='group-username'])[1]/input"))).send_keys('a')
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I've implemented your suggestion and now it is working. I'm not sure I understand the solution entirely tho. You said 'That would get the first iframe use a more targeted xpath.' Does that mean I didn't switch correctly to the iframe? How come I was able to find the first div object but not any other objects in the iframe?

Comment: The rest of the elements are not in the iframe. Like the password and etc.

Comment: I see that the password field is not in the iframe. Since the input object is inbetween <iframe>...</iframe> just like the div object, which I was able to find, I assumed switching to the iframe was successful. I assumed that finding it by its tag_name was good enough since it is the one mentioned first. Guess I was wrong. Using your suggestion with By.XPATH or By.CSS_SELECTOR fixed the problem. Thank you for your help.